# read_only input is not submitting data and form is not valid when bound in symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

So I have an input that has a read_only attribute, in my form type.
When I submit the form that data does not get posted to the page, which is good, and what i expect.

But then when the form is bound (with `->bind()`) and then validated, it is telling me that the inputs need to have a value.

The page is reloaded with no data in the 'read_only' fields.

I expect the bind to realise that the input is read only and not validate it to false, but symfony2 is still trying to read the `read_only` input even thought the data is not submit

Any ideas, or is this correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that seemed to work for me was, I needed to have both the `disabled` and the `read_only` attributes set to true.

---

I now have a better understanding of the attributes, although slightly confusing:

**`read_only`** Will give you a disabled form input, so a user cannot change the value, and the data will not be persisted to the entity when bound (`->bind()`). - If this input is also required and you try to validate it, then it will obviously be false.

**`disabled`** Will leave the input as it is, but ignore all data that the user posts, and not persist it to the entity.

So, even though confusing, you need to use both pretty much at all times